# Question on matrix stability and definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that $AX + XA^*$ is necessarily negative definite if $A$ is stable and $X$ is positive definite. If so, give a proof. If not produce a counter example. I am unable to solve it.

Comment: Did you try to search for "Lyapunov's Stability Theorem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $A=\pmatrix{-1&-2\\ 2&-1}$ and $X=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&2}$, with $AX+XA^\ast=\pmatrix{-8&-2\\ -2&0}$.